# How can I layout two buttons to be the same size?

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-layout

The layout definition is below. Basically I want the two buttons to be the same width, but right now their width is determined by the string they display, is there a better way to lay this out such that the buttons are the same width and that the Button+EditText combo fills the width of the screen?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/editorlinearlayout" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button android:id="@+id/setNameBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" Set Item Name "/>
        <EditText android:id="@+id/nameTxtBox"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button android:id="@+id/setGroupBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Set Group Name"/>
        <EditText android:id="@+id/groupTxtBox"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit**:
I've tried using a TableLayout as was suggested below, but now the EditText's don't fill the remaining portion of the screen. See the image and layout below.

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow>
        <Button android:id="@+id/setNameBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" Set Item Name "/>
        <EditText android:id="@+id/nameTxtBox"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <Button android:id="@+id/setGroupBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Set Group Name"/>
        <EditText android:id="@+id/groupTxtBox"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the trick is to combine the tableview defined in the edit above with a **strechColumn** tag:

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="1">
  <TableRow>
    <Button android:id="@+id/setNameBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Set Item Name "/>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/nameTxtBox"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) and [TableRow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html)s.

Answer (score 1):

Three options:

1. Put this in a TableLayout instead of the nested LinearLayout thing you are currently doing
2. Change your nesting from a vertical parent with horizontal children to a horizontal parent with vertical children (however, this opens up possible vertical positioning issues, so I don't favor this option)
3. Use a RelativeLayout and all of the layout_* attributes that RelativeLayout children have available to them

I'd favor option 1, personally.

Comment: thanks for the tip, but how can I get the edittext to fill the remaining part of the screen

Answer (score 0):

you can use specific width and height for laout_width/layout_height, as in layout_width="150dip".  You run the risk of having a button that can't fit all your text though, but if your text is fixed, you can double check to make sure it's all good.